# Stopping setInterval() after 2 second

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have tried set interval, so that the function computercardArrange()  should be called called only one time after 2 second. But it is calling the function computercardArrange() countiniously after 2 sec. How can i stop so that the function  computercardArrange() is called only one time after 2 sec. Below is the code.

```
function timer() {
setInterval(function(){

    computercardArrange(); // This function should be called only one time after 2 second.


    }, 2000);   
}
```

Comment: You should use the function `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: have you tried setTimeout?

Answer (score 5):

Just use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead

```
function timer() {
setTimeout(function(){
    computercardArrange(); // This function should be called only one time after 2 second.
    }, 2000);   
}
```

> What if i want to call that function 10 times and the stop the
>   interval?

```
var callCount = 0 ;     

function timer() {
var intervalIdentifier = setInterval(function(){
    computercardArrange(); 

    if (++ callCount  == 10) { 
         clearInterval(intervalIdentifier);
    }

    }, 2000);   
}
```

Comment: What if i want  to call that function 10 times and the stop the interval?